KeyError in SimpleSequentialChain
llm are created using WatsonxLLM class.
I'm getting error for the below code:
in validate_chains
for chain in values["chains"]:
KeyError: 'chains'
from langchain_core.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.chains.sequential import SimpleSequentialChain

prompt_1 = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["topic"],
    template="Generate a random question about {topic}: Question: "
    )
prompt_2 = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["question"],
    template="Answer the following question: {question}",
    )

llm1 = flan_ul2_llm
prompt_to_flan_ul2 = prompt_1 | llm1
llm2 = flan_t5_llm
flan_to_t5 = prompt_2 | llm2
qa = SimpleSequentialChain(chains=[prompt_to_flan_ul2, flan_to_t5])
qa.invoke('weather')


I found the same error on my test. I search around and SequentialChain is being deprecated.
In this GitHub chain, they indicate using LCEL is the solution, but no code snipped is provided.
I was originally playing with the code below:
from langchain import PromptTemplate
from langchain_google_genai import GoogleGenerativeAI
from langchain.chains import SimpleSequentialChain

llm = GoogleGenerativeAI(model="gemini-pro", google_api_key=GOGGLE_API_KEY)
# First prompt
template = """
You are an expert data scientist with an expertise in building deep learning models. 
Explain the concept of {concept} in 200 words
"""
prompt = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["concept"],
    template=template,
)
chain = prompt | llm

# Define a second prompt 
second_prompt = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["ml_concept"],
    template="Turn the concept description of {ml_concept} and explain it to me like I'm five in 500 words",
)
chain_two = second_prompt | llm

overall_chain = SimpleSequentialChain(chains=[chain, chain_two])
# Run the chain specifying only the input variable for the first chain.
explanation = overall_chain.run("autoencoder")
print(explanation)

After LCEL usage, the code looks like this:
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.schema import StrOutputParser
from langchain.schema.runnable import RunnablePassthrough
from langchain_google_genai import GoogleGenerativeAI

llm = GoogleGenerativeAI(model="gemini-pro", google_api_key=GOGGLE_API_KEY)


template = """
You are an expert data scientist with an expertise in building deep learning models. 
Explain the concept of {concept} in 200 words
"""

prompt = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["concept"],
    template=template,
)

second_prompt = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["structure"],
    template="Turn the concept description of {structure} and explain it to me like I'm five in 500 words",
)
structure_chain = prompt | llm | StrOutputParser()
review_chain = second_prompt | llm | StrOutputParser()

chain = ({"structure" : structure_chain} 
         | RunnablePassthrough.assign(review=review_chain)
        )
result = chain.invoke({"concept": 'car'})
result

Most of the LCEL ideas come from here
Hope this helps

Why they change something simple that was working for something more complicated and prone to error is beyond me

What is "review" in RunnablePassthrough.assign(review=review_chain)?
